# git push having weird behavior?

Tags: git, git-push, repository, git-clone, atlassian-sourcetree

So I'm in the process of learning Git and I'm using the sourcetree GUI. I have a remote repository on server A(not a bare repo but a working one). So i cloned the remote repo onto my local machine and then I created a new file called "blah.txt" and then added, committed the changes to the local repo.

Then after setting `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore` , i pushed to the remote repo from the local repo. However, after the push, I can't see the file I created(blah.txt) in the remote repo.

However, when I clone the same remote repo into a different folder onto my local machine, blah.txt appears again. Can anyone explain whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

`git push` only pushes the changes into the `.git` directory in the remote repo, but it does not update the files in the working directory of the remote repo.

You can say `git reset --hard` in the remote repo to update the files, but if there were uncommitted edits to some files, you will lose those changes. (You can even make a git hook that runs `git reset --hard` if you want the files automatically updated every time a pull is received.)